# Applying user provided function on groupby object

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```
pri_col col1 col2        Date
     r1    3    4  2020-09-10
     r1    4    1  2020-09-10
     r2    2    7  2020-09-11
     r2    6    4  2020-09-11
```

I am performing a groupby on pri_col and date columns and then applying a function on the rest of the columns.

But the issue here is that I need to take the function as input from the user. Eg.

```
func = input('Function to use: ')
ret_df = ip_df.groupby(['pri_col','date']).apply(eval(func))
```

But this applies the function on pri_col and date also, which is not desired.

Eg. If user provides 'sum' as input, I want the final output to be like,

```
pri_col col1 col2        Date
     r1    7    5   2020-09-10
     r2    8    11  2020-09-11
```

Is there any other approach to this problem? I have tried removing .apply() and using .eval() directly, but we can't do that to groupby object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this trick - convert columns to `MultiIndex`, so not processing by function:

```
ret_df = ip_df.set_index(['pri_col','date']).groupby(['pri_col','date']).apply(eval(func))
```

For oldier pandas version use:

```
ret_df = ip_df.set_index(['pri_col','date']).groupby(level=[0, 1]).apply(eval(func))
```